# bq shell project Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been testing out the bq module as we are looking at using bigquery. I have a project setup and the api's authorised. When I run `bq shell` I am dropped into the shell correctly with the correct project name however, when I try and run `mk dataset_name`. I get the following error:
BigQuery error in mk operation: Not Found: Project dataset_name.

I have tried re-authenticating a couple of times but nothing makes a difference.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a default project ID. If you are using the Google Cloud SDK, `gcloud` will set up a default project for you. You can also use `bq init` to set a default project. Alternately, you can just pass the project_id you want to use on the command line, as `bq --project_id=<your_project_id> shell`. Finally, your other options specify the project when creating the dataset as in `>mk your_project_id:dataset_name` from the `bq` shell.

Comment: Nope it is not that as I created it via the google cloud sdk, I have also tried the `bq mk project:dataset` and it still says 'Not Found: Project dataset'

Comment: Arh may be a bug really then; I was using project name not ID, which i guess is also what the default mk command does if you do not specify. If i use the ID then it works ok. - Thanks